# Mysql CONCAT() is not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql

i have problem with CONCAT mysql function

Mysql Quesry is

```
SELECT CONCAT(a_firstname,' ',a_lastname) as a_employeename FROM employee.
```

This gives null if any of field is null

```
+--------------------------+
| a_firstname | a_lastname |
----------------------------
| bh          | a          |
| a           | NULL       |
+--------------------------+
```

Result

```
+----------------+
| a_employeename |
------------------
| bh             |
| NULL           |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL treats NULL “no data”, So anything could be club with NULL become NULL.
So to avoid this  you must put IFNULL(field,result).

See following query:

`SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(a_firstname,''),' ',IFNULL(a_lastname,'')) as a_employeename FROM employee`

Thanks.

Comment: `COALESCE` use is better as it is standard SQL query. `IFNULL` is not standard SQL query and you may have difficulty in porting your data to databases to other DBMS

Answer (score 6):

Let's begin with a lesson in humility: `CONCAT` *is* working properly, but *you* are not using it right. Please don't jump to conclusions so eagerly.

The problem here is that you must use `COALESCE` when concatenating `NULL` values:

```
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(a_firstname, ''),' ', COALESCE(a_lastname, ''))
```

This is because any operation that involves `NULL` (such as concatenating `NULL` with a string) also results in `NULL`. See [problems with NULL values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-null.html).

Answer (score 1):

just use `IFNULL` function

try this code

```
SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(a_firstname,''),' ',IFNULL(a_lastname,'')) as a_employeename FROM employee.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make CONCAT and one of the fields is NULL, the result is always NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate both NULL and NOT NULL fields, CONCAT_WS() is the best solution.
Example:
     CONCAT_WS(',', FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) will return 'FIELD1Value,FIELD2Value,FIELD3Value'. 
If FIELD2Value is NULL, output will be 'FIELD1Value,FIELD3Value'.